# Spring Security Login page authentication by ip address

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the next spring security config:

```
 <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <access-denied-handler ref="myAccessDeniedHandler" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/categories**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') and hasIpAddress('1.1.1.1')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/donateproject" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />  
    <form-login login-page="/logining" default-target-url="/categories"  authentication-failure-url="/fail2login" 
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="myAuthErrorHandler" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logining" />
  <csrf disabled="true"/>
  </http>
```

Now I am trying to access *"/"* page and get expected *logining* page. When I use wrong ip - it forwards me to *ErrorHandler*. And access is denied even if I have correct username/password. BUT. If I go back inside browser by pushing back button to *logining* page and enter correct username/password, access is granted((( And ip address is not checked. I suppose I need to defend *logining* page as well but this page should not be defended((( How can I overcome such behavior.

Comment: Could you try adding the cache header and test. This has to be added after your `<csrf>` tag inside `http`  `<security:headers>
        <security:cache-control />
     </security:headers>`

Restart the app and let me know!

Comment: The same. The problem is that /logining url is not protected(( I can just type /logining in my browser and get access without ip address check.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some reasonable answer:

1. Page for logining should never be protected. To do it, use:
2. So to protect resource with IP check, this checking should be added to the requested page, in my case it is default page (when I go back in browser) - */categories*, not *"/"*. So it is as simple as:

I hope it will help somebody. Spent the whole day for it.